# how to achieve java format as follows

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image][image]

I've tried google-java-format and other plugins but they're still on a list, my editor is vscode, and  it's default format xml file is eclipse style , I would like to know how to set it to achieve my requirements.

Comment: In eclipse there is an option to prevent putting manual breaks back together

Comment: The linefeed of the stream operation can be preserved after a restart, but the issue about template will not work ，anyhow the first thing is resolved.